# Visual Studio Code take 70% CPU

Tags: windows, visual-studio, memory, visual-studio-code, ram

I just open one project in Visual Studio Code and it takes 70% CPU.

### This is CPU before start Visual Studio Code

[image]

### This is CPU after start Visual Studio Code

[image]

Can any other infornmation I can share to find the reason about that?

Comment: You can share your CPU specifics for a start and VS version, plugins etc...

Comment: @SamuilPetrov I have edited the question

Answer (score 2):

It may be problem with extensions. Try following command in cmd - `code --disable-extensions`. After restart check again.